# Azure Monitor - Log Analytics - Performance Counters - On-prem processes

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

How do I log the running processes for on-prem machines.

I'm successfully tracking the processes for CPU usage.
I'm trying to get the user name of the person who started the process and also the memory levels.

Basically, I'm trying to get some of the data we all have access to in Windows Task Manager.

Any references are much appreciated.
If there's a cheap alternative to this that's not SCOM, I'm open to learning more.

ty

Comment: If I misunderstand in some place, pls add more details in the question, and if you feel my post is helpful to you, could you pls accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may refer to [Azure monitor - Log Analytics agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/log-analytics-agent), it provides the service of collecting telemetry from on-premises machines and those monitored by System Center Operations Manager.

And the cost of log analytics agent, the agent itself doesn't have cost, but you may need to pay for the data ingested. The amount of data ingestion can be considerable depending on the following factors:

- Number of management solutions enabled and their configuration
- Number of VMs monitored
- Type of data collected from each monitored VM

You can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/manage-cost-storage) for more details.